# How to add another candlestick graph in chartSeries in R?

Tags: r, candlestick-chart, dynamic-chart-series

I am not familiar with R.

After plotting a chartSeries graph, how to add another stock's candlestick graph under the first one?

I searched the web but cannot find any information.

Is it related to `rechart`?

Thanks a lot

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")
library("quantmod")
library(rvest)
library(pbapply)
library(TTR)
library(dygraphs)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
pacman::p_load(dygraphs,DT,quantmod)

getSymbols('AAPL', src="yahoo")
getSymbols('FB', src="yahoo")

chartSeries(AAPL)
chartSeries(FB)
```